# Itext PDF Large Fields

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a problem. I'm trying to fill a PDF with a large fields, and the processor writes text at the center of fields, instead of at top left. The code is

```
PdfTextFormField priceField = (PdfTextFormField) fields.get("pagamenti_prenotazione");
        priceField.setMultiline(true);
        priceField.setValue(priceString.toString(), regularFont, regularFontSize);
```

[image: pdf_module]
[image: pdf]

How can I position text on the top left?